# Finding a specific $\mathbb{R}^3$ basis from $3$ vectors following a "simple" equation

Tags: linear-algebra, 3d

After 3 weeks of trying to solve this equation, I come here for help. I have never seen this equation before, and even though it feels simple and straightforward, it doesn't seem to have any intuitive solution.

Here it goes. Let there be $3$ unitary vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$, namely $\vec{V_1}$, $\vec{V_2}$ and $\vec{V_3}$, without any more priors.

Find all unitary vectors $\vec{X}$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$ verifying the following equation :
$$ \sum\limits_{i=1}^3 (\vec{V_i} \times \vec{X}) (\vec{V_i}.\vec{X}) = \vec{0}$$

I talk about a basis in the title as I have very good hints that the solution vectors form an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$. Also, one can show that if $\vec{X_1}$ and $\vec{X_2}$ verify that equation, then $\vec{X_1}\times \vec{X_2}$ also does.

If anyone here have seen that equation somewhere, or has a clue about the solution, I'd be forever thankful !
Thanks !

Edit : I realized that this formulation is equivalent to finding the eigenvectors of the following matrix :

$$
M = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & v_{12} & v_{13} \\
v_{12} & 1 & v_{23} \\
v_{13} & v_{23} & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
With $v_{ij} = \vec{V_i}.\vec{V_j}$.
So the eigenvectors form indeed an orthogonal basis, yet I couldn't find a simple analytic solution. The third degree polynomial one has to solve doesn't seem to have any obvious root. Can anyone confirm that, or have a decent analytical form for those vectors ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

Let $\vec{V}_1$, $\vec{V}_2$, and $\vec{V}_3$ be arbitrary non-parallel vectors, i.e.
$$\left\lbrace \begin{array}{c}
0 \lt \left\lvert \vec{V}_1 \cdot \vec{V}_2 \right\rvert \lt \left\lVert \vec{V}_1\right\rVert \left\lVert \vec{V}_2\right\rVert \\
0 \lt \left\lvert \vec{V}_1 \cdot \vec{V}_3 \right\rvert \lt \left\lVert \vec{V}_1\right\rVert \left\lVert \vec{V}_3\right\rVert \\
0 \lt \left\lvert \vec{V}_2 \cdot \vec{V}_3 \right\rvert \lt \left\lVert \vec{V}_2\right\rVert \left\lVert \vec{V}_3\right\rVert \\
\end{array} \right. \tag{1}\label{EQ1}$$
With these, you can use the [Gram-Schmidt process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram-Schmidt) to form an orthonormal basis $\hat{e}_1$, $\hat{e}_2$, and $\hat{e}_3$ such that
$$\left\lbrace\begin{aligned}
\vec{V}_1 &= \lambda_{1} \hat{e}_1 \\
\vec{V}_2 &= \lambda_{21} \hat{e}_1 + \lambda_{22} \hat{e}_2 \\
\vec{V}_3 &= \lambda_{31} \hat{e}_1 + \lambda_{32} \hat{e}_2 + \lambda_{33} \hat{e}_3 \\
\end{aligned}\right.\tag{2}\label{EQ2}$$
If by "unitary", you mean the vectors are of unit length, then also
$$\left\lbrace\begin{aligned}
\lambda_{1} &= 1 \\
\lambda_{21}^2 + \lambda_{22}^2 &= 1 \\
\lambda_{31}^2 + \lambda_{32}^2 + \lambda_{33}^2 &= 1 \\
\end{aligned}\right.$$
If we use
$$\vec{X} = \left [ \begin{matrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \end{matrix} \right ] \tag{3}\label{EQ3}$$
and $\vec{X}$ is also of unit length, then $x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2 = 1$.

The problem is to find all $\vec{X}$ that fullfill
$$\sum_{i=1}^3 \left(\vec{V}_i \times \vec{X}\right)\left(\vec{V}_i \cdot \vec{X}\right) = \vec{0} \tag{4}\label{EQ4}$$
Applying $\eqref{EQ2}$ and $\eqref{EQ3}$ to $\eqref{EQ4}$, noting that the vector is only zero if each of its components is zero, we get the set of three equations
$$\left\lbrace\begin{aligned}
- (\lambda_{31} \lambda_{33}) x_1 x_2 & + ~ \\
  (\lambda_{21} \lambda_{22} + \lambda_{31} \lambda_{32} ) x_1 x_3 & + ~\\
- (\lambda_{32} \lambda_{33}) x_2^2 & + ~ \\
  (\lambda_{22}^2 + \lambda_{32}^2 - \lambda_{33}^2) x_2 x_3 & + ~ \\
  (\lambda_{32} \lambda_{33}) x_3^2 & = 0 \\
  (\lambda_{31} \lambda_{33}) x_1^2 & + ~ \\
  (\lambda_{32} \lambda_{33}) x_1 x_2 & + ~ \\
  (\lambda_{33}^2 - \lambda_{1}^2 - \lambda_{21}^2 - \lambda_{31}^2) x_1 x_3 & + ~ \\
- (\lambda_{21} \lambda_{22} + \lambda_{31} \lambda_{32}) x_2 x_3 & + ~ \\
- \lambda_{31} \lambda_{33} x_3^2 & = 0 \\
 - (\lambda_{21} \lambda_{22} + \lambda_{31} \lambda_{32}) x_1^2 & + ~ \\
   (\lambda_{1}^2 - \lambda_{22}^2 + \lambda_{21}^2 + \lambda_{31}^2 - \lambda_{32}^2) x_1 x_2 & + ~ \\
 - (\lambda_{32} \lambda_{33}) x_1 x_3 & + ~ \\
   (\lambda_{21} \lambda_{22} + \lambda_{31} \lambda_{32}) x_2^2 & + ~ \\
   (\lambda_{31} \lambda_{33}) x_2 x_3 & = 0 \\
\end{aligned}\right.\tag{5}\label{EQ5}$$
As a set of equations $\eqref{EQ5}$ does not have any interesting solutions (just complicated expressions for $x_2$ and $x_3$ with a free $x_1$, for example), but if indeed "unitary" is used here to mean "of unit length", then many of the terms simplify a lot.

Also note that for example the first of the three equations can also be written as
$$\left[\begin{matrix} x_1 & x_2 & x_3 \end{matrix}\right] \cdot
\left[\begin{matrix} 0 & -\lambda_{31}\lambda_{33} & \lambda_{21}\lambda_{22} + \lambda_{31}\lambda_{32} \\
0 & -\lambda_{32}\lambda_{33} & \lambda_{22}^2 + \lambda_{32}^2  - \lambda_{33}^2 \\
0 & 0 & \lambda_{32}\lambda_{33} \\
\end{matrix}\right] \cdot \left[\begin{matrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \end{matrix} \right] = 0$$
as can the two others as well; you essentially get three matrices that all yield zero when pre- and post-multiplied by the set of vectors fulfilling the specified conditions $\eqref{EQ4}$.
This may or may not help, depending on what OP means by "unitary".

Answer (score 0):

If $$\mathbf{V} = \left [ \begin{matrix} \vec{V}_1 & \vec{V}_2 & \vec{V}_3 \end{matrix} \right ]$$ is an unitary matrix, then $\mathbf{V}$ is an $\mathbb{R}^3$ basis.  Then, we can define
$$\vec{X} = x_1 \vec{V}_1 + x_2 \vec{V}_2 + x_3 \vec{V}_3$$
and the equation
$$\left(\vec{V}_1\times\vec{X}\right)\left(\vec{V}_1\cdot\vec{X}\right) +
\left(\vec{V}_2\times\vec{X}\right)\left(\vec{V}_2\cdot\vec{X}\right) +
\left(\vec{V}_3\times\vec{X}\right)\left(\vec{V}_3\cdot\vec{X}\right) = \vec{0}$$
becomes
$$\begin{align}
\vec{V}_1 \times \left( x_1 \vec{V}_1 + x_2 \vec{V}_2 + x_3 \vec{V}_3 \right)\left( \vec{V}_1 \cdot \left( x_1 \vec{V}_1 + x_2 \vec{V}_2 + x_3 \vec{V}_3 \right)\right)  &~+ \\
\vec{V}_2 \times \left( x_1 \vec{V}_1 + x_2 \vec{V}_2 + x_3 \vec{V}_3 \right)\left( \vec{V}_2 \cdot \left( x_1 \vec{V}_1 + x_2 \vec{V}_2 + x_3 \vec{V}_3 \right)\right)  &~+ \\
\vec{V}_3 \times \left( x_1 \vec{V}_1 + x_2 \vec{V}_2 + x_3 \vec{V}_3 \right)\left( \vec{V}_3 \cdot \left( x_1 \vec{V}_1 + x_2 \vec{V}_2 + x_3 \vec{V}_3 \right)\right)  & = \vec{0} \\
\end{align}$$
which simplifies to
$$\begin{align}
\vec{V}_1 \times \left( x_1 \vec{V}_1 + x_2 \vec{V}_2 + x_3 \vec{V}_3 \right) x_1 \left\lVert \vec{V}_1 \right\rVert^2  &~+ \\
\vec{V}_2 \times \left( x_1 \vec{V}_1 + x_2 \vec{V}_2 + x_3 \vec{V}_3 \right) x_2 \left\lVert \vec{V}_2 \right\rVert^2  &~+ \\
\vec{V}_3 \times \left( x_1 \vec{V}_1 + x_2 \vec{V}_2 + x_3 \vec{V}_3 \right) x_3 \left\lVert \vec{V}_3 \right\rVert^2  & = \vec{0} \\
\end{align}$$
and to
$$\begin{align}
\left( \vec{V}_1 \times \vec{V}_2 \right ) x_1 x_2 \left( \left\lVert\vec{V}_1\right\rVert^2 - \left\lVert\vec{V}_2\right\rVert^2 \right ) & ~+ \\
\left( \vec{V}_1 \times \vec{V}_3 \right ) x_1 x_3 \left( \left\lVert\vec{V}_1\right\rVert^2 - \left\lVert\vec{V}_3\right\rVert^2 \right ) & ~+ \\
\left( \vec{V}_2 \times \vec{V}_3 \right ) x_2 x_3 \left( \left\lVert\vec{V}_2\right\rVert^2 - \left\lVert\vec{V}_3\right\rVert^2 \right ) & = \vec{0} \\
\end{align}$$
and then to
$$\begin{align}
\vec{V}_3 \frac{\left\lVert\vec{V}_1\right\rVert \left\lVert\vec{V}_2\right\rVert}{\left\lVert\vec{V}_3\right\rVert} x_1 x_2 \left( \left\lVert\vec{V}_1\right\rVert^2 - \left\lVert\vec{V}_2\right\rVert^2 \right ) & ~+ \\
\vec{V}_2 \frac{\left\lVert\vec{V}_1\right\rVert \left\lVert\vec{V}_3\right\rVert}{\left\lVert\vec{V}_2\right\rVert} x_1 x_3 \left( \left\lVert\vec{V}_3\right\rVert^2 - \left\lVert\vec{V}_1\right\rVert^2 \right ) & ~+ \\
\vec{V}_1 \frac{\left\lVert\vec{V}_2\right\rVert \left\lVert\vec{V}_3\right\rVert}{\left\lVert\vec{V}_1\right\rVert} x_2 x_3 \left( \left\lVert\vec{V}_2\right\rVert^2 - \left\lVert\vec{V}_3\right\rVert^2 \right ) & = \vec{0} \\
\end{align}$$
Because the basis vectors are orthogonal, the coefficient for each basis vector must vanish separately; $\vec{X} = \vec{0}$ if and only if $x_1 = x_2 = x_3 = 0$. If $\left\lVert\vec{V}_i\right\rVert \gt 0$, then the above sum is equivalent to
$$\begin{cases}
x_1 x_2 \left( \left\lVert\vec{V}_1\right\rVert^2 - \left\lVert\vec{V}_2\right\rVert^2 \right ) = 0 \\
x_1 x_3 \left( \left\lVert\vec{V}_3\right\rVert^2 - \left\lVert\vec{V}_1\right\rVert^2 \right ) = 0 \\
x_2 x_3 \left( \left\lVert\vec{V}_2\right\rVert^2 - \left\lVert\vec{V}_3\right\rVert^2 \right ) = 0 \\
\end{cases}$$
Besides $x_1 = x_2 = x_3 = 0$, this has three types of solutions:
$$\begin{array}{ll}
\text{1.} & x_1 \ne 0, & x_2 = 0, & x_3 = 0 \\
\text{2.} & x_1 = 0, & x_2 \ne 0, & x_3 = 0 \\
\text{3.} & x_1 = 0, & x_2 = 0, & x_3 \ne 0 \\
\end{array}$$
In other words, all vectors $\vec{X}$ parallel to one of the vectors $\vec{V}_i$ fulfill the equation.

A more general approach is to expand the original equation in terms of $\mathbf{V}$ and $\vec{x} = \left[ \begin{matrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \end{matrix} \right ]$.

Comment: No, since $V$ may be a basis - let's assume that- but its not necessarily orthogonal. So $\vec{V_1} . \vec{V_2} \neq 0$, and that unfortunately is the difficulty here.